# Angular 6 - ERROR DOMException: Failed to execute 'setAttribute' on 'Element':

Tags: javascript, angular, dom, domexception

I'm new with Angular 6 . I have assigned public property at component.js file and the values are not rendering in the component.html file. I have attached chrome log , component.ts and component.html file.

It would be highly appreciated if you can let me know where I'm doing wrong.

[image: html file]    [image: script file]    [image: Chrome colsole log]

Comment: you should have to write like this - <option *ngFor="let m for data" value="{{m.id}}">{{m.name}}</option>

Comment: Try to use: <div *ngIf="data"></div>//Your HTML Code

Comment: And use  <option *ngFor="let m for data" [value]="m.id">{{m.name}}</option

Comment: You have an error in your syntax, you need to close the `<option>` tag before `{{m.name}}`.

Comment: Yes agreed with @GiacomoVoß

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your error says it so clearly that you are doing something wrong with `{{m.name}}`. It is trying to add it as an attribute because you mention it inside the `attribute` section which is invalid.

Move it to the `content` section i.e between the opening and closing tags.

Change it this way :

```
<option *ngFor="let m for data" value="{{m.id}}">{{m.name}}</option>
```